# Javascript and Animate-cc code interaction

Tags: javascript, animate-cc

i'm just new with Animate CC and trying to understand how it works.

I did this example:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    fps: 60,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: [
        {src:"sounds/_30_reel.mp3?1472134036249", id:"_30_reel"}
    ]
};



// symbols:



(lib.Simbolo2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Livello 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#000000").ss(1,1,1).p("AImAAQAACqihB4QiiB4jjAAQjiAAiih4Qihh4AAiqQAAipChh4QCih4DiAAQDjAACiB4QChB4AACpg");
    this.shape.setTransform(55,41);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#0066CC").s().p("AmDEiQiih5AAipQAAipCih4QCgh4DjAAQDjAAChB4QChB4AACpQAACpihB5QihB4jjgBQjjABigh4g");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(55,41);

    this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_2.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AmDEiQiih5AAipQAAipCih4QCgh4DjAAQDjAAChB4QChB4AACpQAACpihB5QihB4jjgBQjjABigh4g");
    this.shape_2.setTransform(55,41);

    this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_3.graphics.f("#000000").s().p("AmDEiQiih5AAipQAAipCih4QCgh4DjAAQDjAAChB4QChB4AACpQAACpihB5QihB4jjgBQjjABigh4g");
    this.shape_3.setTransform(55,41);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_2},{t:this.shape}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]},1).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-1,-1,112,84);


(lib.Fx = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{Stop:29});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }
    this.frame_29 = function() {
        playSound("_30_reel");
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(29).call(this.frame_29).wait(1));

    // Livello 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#000000").s().p("AAHAnIAAgCIAFgBIACgBIABgCIAAgDIgDgFIgMgVIgRAWIgDAEIAAADIABADIAGABIAAACIgcAAIAAgCIAFgBIAHgEIAIgIIASgYIgPgVQgHgJgEgDQgEgDgGAAIAAgCIAkAAIAAACIgGABQAAABgBAAQAAAAAAABQAAAAgBAAQAAABAAAAQAAADADAEIAKASIAOgSIADgEIABgDIgBgCIgCgBIgFgBIAAgCIAcAAIAAACIgGABIgGAEIgHAIIgQAUIARAYQAHAKAEADQADADAGAAIAAACg");
    this.shape.setTransform(13,8.8);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#000000").s().p("AgdAnIAAgCIADAAQAFAAADgDQABgCAAgHIAAgxIgBgIIgDgDQgCgBgDAAIgDAAIAAgCIA5AAIABARIgBAAIgEgIQgCgDgDgBIgJgBIgQAAIAAAfIANAAQAFAAACgCQACgCABgHIACAAIAAAZIgCAAQAAgEgBgCQgBgBAAAAQAAgBgBAAQAAgBgBAAQAAgBgBAAIgFgBIgNAAIAAAZQAAAGABACIACADIAEABIACAAIAAACg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(5.2,8.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]},29).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,19.5,17.5);


(lib.formabase = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{A:0,B:19});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }
    this.frame_19 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(19).call(this.frame_19).wait(1));

    // Livello 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#000000").ss(1,1,1).p("Az1spMAnrAAAIAAZTMgnrAAAg");
    this.shape.setTransform(127,81);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#0066CC").s().p("Az1MqIAA5TMAnqAAAIAAZTg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(127,81);

    this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_2.graphics.f("#FF0066").s().p("Az1MqIAA5TMAnqAAAIAAZTg");
    this.shape_2.setTransform(127,81);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_2},{t:this.shape}]},19).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-1,-1,256,164);


(lib.Simbolo1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(40));

    // Livello 1
    this.ani2 = new lib.formabase();
    this.ani2.setTransform(127,81,1,1,0,0,0,127,81);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.ani2).to({x:663,y:-3},39).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-0.5,-0.5,255,163);


// stage content:



(lib.index = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.button.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToPosition.bind(this));

        function fl_ClickToPosition() {
            this.ani.ani2.gotoAndStop("B");
            this.ani.play();
        }
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(1));

    // Fx
    this.fx = new lib.Fx();
    this.fx.setTransform(390.8,85,1,1,0,0,0,9.8,8.7);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.fx, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.Fx(), 3);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.fx).wait(1));

    // Livello 1
    this.button = new lib.Simbolo2();
    this.button.setTransform(121,160,1,1,0,0,0,55,41);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.button, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.Simbolo2(), 3);

    this.ani = new lib.Simbolo1();
    this.ani.setTransform(485,292,1,1,0,0,0,127,81);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.ani},{t:this.button}]}).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(705,436.3,547.5,297.3);

})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

and it works fine.

Now I'm wondering how can achieve this behaviour to move the ani2 to label "B" from another Javascript file.
If I try to put this code this.ani.ani2.gotoAndStop("B"); in the html it doesn't work.
What I'm missing?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to an initialization bug, where you can't call `gotoAndStop` immediately after initialization.

Just to test this, I added the following lines to the html file generated by Adobe Animate:

```
    exportRoot.ani.gotoAndStop(0);
    exportRoot.ani.ani2.gotoAndStop(19);
```

The first line forces a child/timeline update on the `ani` clip, which makes the 2nd line work properly.

This is a known issue, and on the short list to solve for the next version of CreateJS that will be included in Adobe Animate.

Cheers.

Comment: This has been solved in CreateJS 1.0, but Adobe has not yet updated the version they use.